# A clear picture of the casaulties of the Jewish people under the Third Reich

Tags: nazi-germany, jews, holocaust, revisionism

I know this is a pretty sensitive question, but I would like to get an objective answer. It is widely known that the Jewish people were persecuted by Hitler's regime, and many of them died in the concentration camps.
But I never feel like the numbers are exact, from time to time I see people's documentation about the Holocaust and the numbers are changing in wide range.

My problem is:
- first of all, there are the neo-nazis, who claim that the Holocaust never happened. Ok, that seems totally false.
- second of all, there are some Soviet-era and even some American claims about the numbers which are also looking falsified. I wouldn't wonder since there was a war which was won, and the winner always try to support their views. Especially the Soviet data is not really reliable.

I see some attempts to get a clear picture, for example David Cole's interviews in Auschwitz. He made a low-cost documentary on this subject in 1992. He seems to me a little bit more reliable than some Soviet-era officiers or the neo-nazi sources. He claims that - and it is pretty believable to me - the Germans mostly forced the Jews to work and more of the Jews died in poor conditions than in the gas chambers.
But since I am not an Historian I can't really judge it.

So the point of the question is: **Is there any normal objective source on this subject?**

Comment: If you decide to visit Auschwitz one day, feel free to contact me for any help. I live only 60 kilometers from there.

Comment: Scholars who study Nazism, World War II, and the Holocaust are diverse and international. There is no central authority to which they report and no headquarters to enforce a single view. The fact that they all agree on the broad outlines of what happened (while still arguing about factual details and historical explanations) shows that the evidence is unequivocal.

Comment: @DarekWędrychowski Thank you, it is a kind gesture, I can't promise, but I am willing to investigate these places. I am 32 years old, and I have no close connection to holocaust. My family wasn't involved to any kind of state related actions, and I have no jewish relatives as well. I see that some people (some jews and neo nazis) get hysterical if the holocaust gets to topic. I am simply a person for whom this is history. I was never involved, just by historical records, and I see that instead of getting exact answers I often get just emotional based critics. I want to understand why.

Comment: I have *not* flagged this Question for attention by the moderators. Basing a Q on a source as dubious as David Cole / "David Stein", a scurrilous holocaust minimizer, impostor, and con man, darling of Nazis, is about as deserving of respect as basing a question about "ancient aliens" on Erich von Däniken and calling his claims "pretty believable". What I find disheartening is that currently this Q stands at 3 net upvotes. Instead, it should be downvoted into oblivion. Maybe "the community" is made up of stupid mouth breathers. Or maybe I am wrong and this is a good Question.

Comment: @EugeneSeidel Thanks for the recent info on David Cole, from the source I can agree, he is not acceptable source on holocaust. My opinion is, the holocaust research is somewhat "in one hand" which makes me have a feeling that it have a chance the numbers could be modified. I can easily believe that the soviets altered the numbers to justify their barbarism, and also the western allies could (i have no proof) modify the numbers to support a propaganda. I think the question is valid, and I am sure there shouldn't be sacred cows in history which can't be questioned, just because it is tragic.

Comment: _"a feeling ... have a chance could be ... can easily believe .... i have no proof ..."_. I rest my case.

Comment: @EugeneSeidel see? That's exactly why I am asking the question :) If I was sure about all these things I wouldn't ask.

Comment: Shows the lack of basic research suitable for a good question.

Comment: @CsBalazsHungary the Nazis themselves kept meticulous records of the number of people shipped off to the camps, those have been studied and counted and recounted over decades. Only holocaust deniers believe those records are fakes or don't exist at all. If the only source about the holocaust were Soviet propaganda pamphlets you'd have a strong point, but that's not the case.

Comment: @EugeneSeidel I certainly understand your feelings about the question and the sense of disappointment with the community. However, the question does indicate, in my opinion a willingness to learn on the OP's part; therefore I neither upvoted nor downvoted.

Comment: @FelixGoldberg not the community as a whole, rather a disturbing group within it. Sadly there is a large subset of conspiracy theorists and a larger subset of those who are influenced by propaganda to the point they believe that what we recognise as blatant lies are in fact factual truth.

Comment: @jwenting: Yes, I know these people. But I think that some of the +6 votes might have come not from them but from people who wanted to give the OP thumbs-up for trying to learn.

Comment: @jwentig the comment about the Nazi's records is probably the kernel to a good answer to this question. This Spiegel article (http://www.spiegel.de/international/fifty-million-nazi-documents-germany-agrees-to-open-holocaust-archive-a-411983.html) from 2006 indicates that the Germans were planning to open those records to the public.  Someone may want to contact the author and ask what the status of that archive is.

Comment: @jwenting I am of course far from denial of holocaust. Yes, jews were executed in concentration camps, many of them. For me it is indifferent if the number was 500.000 or 6 million, either is tragic. I just wanted to clarify David Cole's statements, which was pretty much successful, thanks to Felix Goldberg's links. And I couldn't judge properly what was propaganda, were there false documents, etc. I guess nobody doubts that especially soviets were enthusiastic to fake documents if it was neccessary.

Comment: During decades of communism and state propaganda, east Europeans learned to be suspicious of anything published in history books. You can see this "conspiracist" mindset in OP's comment above _"My opinion is, the holocaust research is somewhat "in one hand" which makes me have a feeling that it have a chance the numbers could be modified."_ Now these folks must unlearn their reflex of automatically assuming the opposite of mainstream teaching to be true. If they do not, bad habits will forever hold them back and handicap them. Holocaust scholarship is not "somewhat in one hand" (continued)

Comment: (cont'd) In fact, historians studying the Holocaust are diverse and international and do not answer to a central authority. However, I repeat myself. I wrote that months ago already and it has not made a dent in OP's thinking, so I am not optimistic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does [this page](http://pages.uoregon.edu/dluebke/Holocaust444-544/CausesofDeath.htm) answer your question?

UPDT: You might also want to gave a good look at [this book](http://books.google.ie/books/about/Denying_History.html?id=uACijKy-cbgC&redir_esc=y). Specifically, search for "David Cole" in it.

UPDT 2: Thanks to Eugene Seidel, we know what is David Cole [up to these days](http://www.guardian.co.uk/world/2013/may/03/david-stein-cole-holocaust-revisionist).

Comment: In particular [this section](http://books.google.ie/books?id=uACijKy-cbgC&q=david+cole#v=snippet&q=david%20cole&f=false), which opens: "The most paradoxical of the deniers is David Cole..."

Comment: It's unfortunate that "this page" is now a 404, without the substance in the answer.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44948/discussion-on-answer-by-felix-goldberg-clear-picture-of-casaulties-of-jewish-peo).

Answer (score 15):

I recommend going to Wikipedia's page on the Holocaust. You have two options. One is to read the article, which is a bit tedious. That is inevitable when you crowdsource the writing of an encyclopedia. On the other hand, that article is among the most watched of all articles on the Wikipedia, so it is unlikely for misinformation to remain in there for long.

The other option would be to skip the entire article body, go straight to its bibliography. Then spend two weeks working through the sources, making sure you also hit the library for paper sources that are not online. If you can find a concentration camp survivor to tell you of their experiences in person, very good: after all, it was not columns of numbers but living, breathing people who were shoved into the cattle cars. But there aren't many left. If not, watch some survivor videos recorded by the Shoah Foundation.

Read the [pre-eminent scholars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aHistorians_of_the_Holocaust): Hilberg, Broszat, Browning, Evans, Friedländer, Kershaw, Lipstadt... Pay attention to where they agree and where they disagree. For contrast, briefly descend into evil/insanity/stupidity by reading David Irving and others of his ilk. If after that you still have doubts that Nazi Germany, together with collaborators in allied nations, waged a campaign of extermination against the Jews and managed to kill more than two-thirds of Europe's Jewish population, then I don't know what more to say to you.

Comment: This should really be the accepted answer. Oh, and maybe add the Nizkor project?

Comment: There is not an explicit "number" nor will there ever be. Most Jews who stayed behind during the 3rd Reich era (1933-1945) did so for two reasons: to fight Communist Russia and once that Victory was one to establish a homeland in present day Israel. There are well documented attempts for Germany to resettle the European Jews in the "East"(the bulk lived in Poland) but Soviet Russia very much saw this as some type of "ruse" to create yet another group of 5th Columnists in "the Bloodlands" between Soviet Russia and Germany. Were these Death Camps or training grounds for the massive Nazi Armies?

Comment: The fact is we will never truly know though tens of millions of everyone died there...some in Camps, some in battle, most as simply settlers living in some town or even major City that happened to be in the way of the two largest Armies that have ever fought in History.

Answer (score 1):

In ["The War Against the Jews,"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_War_Against_the_Jews) Lucy Dawidowitz provides estimates of Jewish casualty rates by country. The book has been challenged by others such as Raul Hilberg, but is still a useful reference.

Comment: just wanted to add  a link about Raul Hilberg, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Destruction_of_the_European_Jews.